# Spotfire - How to update a marking after the data to the chart has been filtered

Tags: spotfire

I have 3 charts on a page Chart 1, Chart 2 and Chart 3 (all bar charts). Each of these charts have their respective markings Marking 1, Marking 2 and Marking 3. Each of these charts are limited by markings of the other 2 charts. For example Chart 1 is limited by Marking 2 and Marking 3 and is displaying all the data when no items are marked from Marking 2 or Marking 3. 
Now Lets say there are a total of 1000 rows and out of which I mark 100 of them in Chart 1 (Marking 1). This triggers and limits the data in Chart 2 and Chart 3.

```
Chart 1 - Marking 1 = 100 rows
Chart 2 - Marking 2 = 0 rows
Chart 3 - Marking 3 = 0 rows
```

Now that Chart 2 is showing a bar chart for only those marked 100 rows, I go ahead and apply a marking on that too, lets say 50 rows.

```
Chart 1 - Marking 1 = 100 rows
Chart 2 - Marking 2 = 50 rows
Chart 3 - Marking 3 = 0 rows
```

When I do this, Chart 3 still shows me data for 100 rows that where marked in Marking 1. As Marking 1 has a bigger subset and contains everything in Marking 2. I have to re-select over my Marked items in Marking 1 , which then makes both Marking 1 and 2 at 50 rows and now Chart 3 is updated.

Is there any way I can fix it, is there a way where I dont have to re-select my markings and Marking 1 automatically gets updated after Marking 2.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately that's the intended behavior for marking interactions.

the workaround I usually implement for this scenario is to include instructions and a button for "reset selection" (or "reset marking" if your users are savvy).

you *may* be able to get around this by using a **Data Function**, but I haven't come across anything to unmark based on other markings, only to perform some action when a marking is made.